# I can't say what's missing in my .net core project...Is my Intellisense not working or what's the reason?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I started learning .net core so I created an Api using dotnet new webapi -o DatingApp.API

My Trainer was getting some hints when he press ctrl+. but I was not getting such hints in my vs code....
[image]

Is my Intellisense not working or what's the reason?
One more point to add....My trainer in his videos has some launch.json and tasks.json in his folder but those files were missing in my Project...

Edited.....I already Installed C# extension and I got Tasks.json and launch.json when I pressed f5 but Intellisense is not working for ctrl+.

Comment: Try to restore the Nuget packages with dotnet restore

Comment: Will try and update u @robjam

Comment: Tried it @robjam its not working, i'm still not able to get namespaces on ctrl+.

Comment: I am getting no code actions available if i press ctrl+. @robjam

Comment: Could you open VSCode from the same directory as the .csproj?
If that works then you may need to create a solution file or add the project to it.
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2327

Comment: I have opened from same directory bruh @robjam ......Where can I see the logs for this omnisharp extension????

Answer (score 0):

if you are using VS CODE, for intellisense to work, you will need to install plugin for C#
and then you will be able to see it when pressing ctrl + space key.

If your trainer had a project.json file he will be using first version of dotnet core (1.0) because the support for project.json was removed after that version

Comment: no he was using .net core 2.0.2 , so he was not having any project.json file

Answer (score 0):

In vs code intellisense does not work automatically, for that you will have install extension for c#. install the c# extension and reopen vs code.[image]

Comment: intellisense is not working for all or only Linq queries?

Comment: @GvsAkhil  Install another extension named as "c# extensions" , reopen vs code and try.

Comment: I already installed that extension too...I was using that to create my c# classes

Comment: If i type prop c# is working there and when i press ctrl+. for adding namespaces its not working @Mohan

Comment: I am getting no code actions available if i press ctrl+.

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder containing the Api to the solution

dotnet sln new projectfoldername

Thereby you will get .csproj file and intellisense will work